# option like TAIL to keep track of WHOLE file

Tags: tail

`tail -f` will update the file once new data is inserted , but if the whole file is being rewritten it will give an error .

is there any other option to keep reloading the whole file ?

Thank you

Answer (score 5):

[`man tail`](http://unixhelp.ed.ac.uk/CGI/man-cgi?tail) gives :

`tail -F` or `tail --follow=name --retry` to keep tail watching file even if all the file is rewritten.

Comment: no it gives 'tail: 1.dat: file truncated' and does not reload the new content

Comment: @RonanDejhero : if you didn't use the `-F` option, add the `--retry` to the `--follow=name`

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at [multitail](http://www.vanheusden.com/multitail/). 
The following output was produced through the command `sudo multitail --follow-all -i /vor/log/syslog`. It shows the end of one file, a notice that the file got truncated and the beginning of the new syslog entry:

```
Nov  8 09:06:36 rfc1178 anacron[22633]: Updated timestamp for job `cron.daily'11-08
tail: �~@~^/var/log/syslog�~@~\ wurde ersetzt;  folge Ende der neuen Datei
----------- file got truncated /var/log/syslog 2012/11/08 09:08:02-----------
Nov  8 09:08:02 rfc1178 rsyslogd: [origin software="rsyslogd" …
```